# Debian based system, only one gui program, nothing else

Tags: debian, kiosk

I would like to make a debian system where you can only open one GUI program at boot, no other graphical interface, no minimize, or any X apart from that program, is there a way to do it on debian if possible, or any other custom distro? I just want to boot open the program and allow the user to only see and use that program.

Comment: Running a single application is called a kiosk; use this word in your searches, including [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiosk).

Comment: I recently was struggling with similar problem and I posted a solution - not debian based, but would work exactly the same way with debian. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344374/how-to-configure-kiosk-with-wayland-xorg Beauty is - only 2 key combinations work (to reboot or to shutdown), system is fast and only has access to browser, normal text input and mouse. No other apps.

Answer (score 14):

I've done that with Ubuntu (Debian based), though I think the technique applies for other distros too. I'll just summarize the steps here together with some explanation, see "[Run Linux with a bare window manager](https://web.archive.org/web/20131210161955/http://phunehehe.is-great.org/2010/run-linux-with-a-bare-window-manager/)" for the scripts.

1. Add a custom session by creating a file at `/usr/share/xsessions/metacity-session.desktop`. This file tells the login manager about your session.
2. Create the file to be executed by the session added in (1) `/usr/local/bin/metacity-session`
3. Create the user-specific config file `~/.metacity-session`. This file will be executed by the file added in (2). The content should be the program you want to run, followed by an ampersand, for example

   ```
   firefox &
   ```
4. Optionally make the user auto-login and make the custom session the default session for the user.

Here I use Metacity as the window manager for its simplicity, you can use Compiz if you want to.

There are tools to lock down the system. A search yields tools such as [sabayon](http://live.gnome.org/Sabayon/) and [pessulus](http://lifehacker.com/5322196/lockdown-editor-controls-activity-on-ubuntu-desktops). I haven't used any of them to give a recommendation.

There are also distros specialized on kiosk mode, the most promising seems to be [Fedora Kiosk Mode](http://spins.fedoraproject.org/kiosk/), though it's not Debian based.

Comment: [Webconverger](http://webconverger.org/) looks interesting in the *specialized distro* department, and is Debian-based.

Comment: The `Run Linux with a bare window manager` link now uses a different definition of bare than you intended!

Comment: @PeterM :D lawl

Comment: @PeterM my old blog, it died </3 replaced with in archive.org link until I bring it back

Answer (score 7):

I know this is a little old but I've written a simple how to on this that works on PCs and the Raspberry PI:

Creating a Debian Chromium Kiosk (PC or Raspberry PI)

- download and install debian

  - PC x64 or i386 : download "standard" iso from debian.org
  - raspberry pi 2/3 : download "raspbian lite" from raspberryip.org

    - use Win32DiskImager to write img to SD card
- after install use apt to install packages

  ```
  apt install --no-install-recommends xorg openbox lightdm chromium pulseaudio
  ```

  - on raspberry pi chromium package is chromium-browser
  - installing packages is slow on raspberry, get a FAST SD card (class 10 or better)
- configure lightdm for autologin

  - edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` goto `[SeatDefaults]` section, uncomment `autologin-user`

    ```
    [SeatDefaults]
    autologin-user={USER}
    ```
  - `{USER}` is defined during debian installer for PC
  - `{USER}` is 'pi' for raspberry pi
- configure openbox to start chromium automatically

  - edit `/etc/xdg/openbox/autostart` or create `~/.config/openbox/autostart` and add these lines:

    ```
    xset -dpms
    xset s off
    chromium --kiosk http://google.com
    ```
  - change google.com to whatever you need
  - the xset commands disable screen savers
  - on raspberry pi chromium is chromium-browser
- to auto connect to Wifi

  - `edit /etc/network/interfaces` and write:

    ```
    auto wlan0
    iface wlan0 inet dhcp
      wpa-ssid {ssid}
      wpa-psk  {password}
    ```
  - replace `{ssid}` and `{password}` with your respective WiFi SSID and password

Comment: You can also modify `xserver-command` on `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` if you want hide mouse cursor. `xserver-command=X -bs -core -nocursor`