# How to create a lite graphical ability for linux server?

Tags: linux, display, x-server, kiosk

I use an Arm-based board(nanopi-m1: http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPi_M1) and an Ubuntu-server ported for my board(armbian: https://www.armbian.com/nanopi-m1) with fbtft support on the kernel, and this framebuffer driver(notro: https://github.com/notro/fbtft) to launch my LCD(2.2" TFT LCD: http://www.elecfreaks.com/wiki/index.php?title=2.2S%22_TFT_LCD:_TFT01-2.2S).

Previously when I used Ubuntu-desktop(Armbian-desktop), I could configure my LCD by this command:

```
sudo modprobe fbtft_device custom name=fb_ili9341 gpios=reset:1,dc:201,led:6 speed=16000000 rotate=90 bgr=1
```

And launch it by this command:

```
FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb8 startx
```

But now I use Ubuntu-server(Armbian-server) and it gives me this error message:

```
-bash: startx: command not found
```

My first question is, how can I fix this problem?

And my second and most important question is, if I want to build a robot, that when user turns it on, it shows my logo, then shows another pic and waiting for user command, then according to users command shows some pics or videos, how can I build it?

I think I am building something like kiosk, but I tried this tutorial([Debian based system, only one gui program, nothing else](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30207/debian-based-system-only-one-gui-program-nothing-else)) and it didn't work(I couldn't login to metacity session). Then I searched and tried some other options but confused about which one is sufficient for me?

Briefly, let's consider I have a program that listens to user's command and shows some pic or video related to the command. I wrote my program in C++, and I think I must use gtk+ to pass some pics or video trough my LCD.

But how can I tell the Linux, only run my program when the system is powered on, and only show my logo and then my interested pic or video according to my program's voice commands recognition.